# Cannot convert type from Class to TClass

Tags: c#, generics

Given the following code:

```
public class CustomSection: Section, ISection
{    
}

public class Section
{
}

public interface ISection
{    
}
```

When I try to return a list of TSection:

```
private List<TSection> Test<TSection>()
    where TSection : Section, ISection
{
    return new List<TSection> { (TSection)(new CustomSection()) };
}
```

I get error 'Can't convert type from 'CustomSection' to 'TSection'.

If I change it to read like this it works:

```
private List<TSection> Test<TSection>()
    where TSection : Section, ISection
{
    return new List<TSection> { (new CustomSection() as TSection) };
}
```

What is the subtle difference between casting that causes one way to error and the other to not?

Comment: Why are you hardcoding the type anyway?

Comment: Did you confirm it returned a valid value? Using `as` won't cause an error, it will just return `null` if it's not a valid cast. Did you verify it isn't `null`?

Comment: A `TSection` is not necessarily a `CustomSection` whiich is why the direct cast fails.

Comment: Also, why does `Section` not implement `ISection`?

Comment: @maccettura ive just provided a simple example. In my real project my concrete is UserControl which of course I have no control of and the interface is mine.

Comment: Also this is the design time error that visual studio is giving. Using 'as' and there is no problem but using () and there is. I'm after what the actual difference is. I suspect it has something to do with when you use 'as' and the cast fails there is no exception thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to cast between two leaf-nodes on your inheritance tree, which is not valid.  Consider a tree rooted on `Animal`.  If both `Dog` and `Cat` extend `Animal`, they are at the same level of inheritance and share a common base class, but you cannot cast a `Dog` to a `Cat`.  You can cast both of them to `Animal`, because it's higher up the tree, but you can't cast to another type at the same level.

In your code, `TSection` and `CustomSection` are both at the same level on the tree, as they both extend `Section` (and `ISection`).  You could cast `CustomSection` to `Section`, but not to `TSection`.  Using `as TSection` will compile, but it will return `null` unless `TSection` is exactly `CustomSection`.

Comment: I don't think it will return null if TSection is CustomSection.

Comment: @SBFrancies, that's true, if `TSection` is `CustomSection`, it will work.